# Limit of a function is equal to $L$ iff limit of absolute value of the function is equal to $|L|$.

Tags: complex-analysis, limits

I've been watching complex analysis videos and it seems that a common technique is to consider the modulus of the complex-valued function and taking the limit instead. I was wondering if this is true:
$$\lim_{z \rightarrow z_0} f(z) = L \iff \lim_{z \rightarrow z_0} |f(z)| = |L|.$$

If so, how would I prove this via epsilon-delta?
I was wondering the validity of proving that
$$\lim_{z \rightarrow -i} (z-i)\mathrm{Log}(z^2 + 1) = L$$
by doing these following steps:
$$L = \lim_{z\rightarrow -i} |z-i||\mathrm{Log}(z^2 + 1)| \\=2\lim_{z\rightarrow -i}|\mathrm{Log}(z^2+1)| = 2\lim_{z\rightarrow -i}|\ln(z^2 +1) + i\mathrm{Arg}(z^2+1)|$$
which goes to infinity since the principle argument function is defined for $z^2 + 1$ for any $z$ but $\ln$ will go to infinity.
Specifically, I'm doubting the step where I took the product of limits in the 2nd equality since the limit was infinite, and also the step where I conclude that the original limit is also infinite.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's consider a simple example,

$$\lim_{z \to 0} |g(z)|=1$$

From your claim, you might have conclude that $$\lim_{z \to 0} g(z)=1$$

However, it is also possible that 
$\forall z, g(z)=-1$

Comment: Ah I see; so in the relation I gave in the OP, it should only be $\Rightarrow$ (when the limit isn't infinite or zero)? How would I "change" the RHS to make it an $\iff$ (if it is possible)?

Comment: Perhaps by rsome domain restriction.  But i doubt that would be useful.

Comment: I see; so the only reason the following limit proof (considering the absolute value) was valid to prove the original limit was because the limit was $\infty$?

Comment: Well, there is only one infinity in complex analysis.

Answer (score 1):

The following implication is true, $$\lim_{z \rightarrow z_0} f(z) = L \implies \lim_{z \rightarrow z_0} |f(z)| = |L|.$$

Assuming, $\lim_{z \rightarrow z_0} f(z) = L$ we have by definition

$\forall$ $\epsilon>0\;\;\exists \delta>0$ such that whenever $z\in D\subseteq\Bbb C  $ and $0<|z-z_0|<\delta\implies|f(z)-L|<\epsilon--------(1)$

From triangle inequality it follows that, $||f(z_1)|-|f(z_2)||\le|f(z_1)-f(z_2)|$  $\forall z_1,z_2\in \Bbb C-----------(2)$

$(1),(2)\implies ||f(z)|-|L||\le|f(z)-L|<\epsilon$, for $z\in D\subseteq\Bbb C  $ and $0<|z-z_0|<\delta$

Hence $\lim_{z \rightarrow z_0} |f(z)| = |L|$.

But the converse is not true. Can you come up with a counterexample?

Comment: Thank you; I thought that limits defined like this had $\delta$ to only be a function of $\epsilon$ and not $z_0$?

Comment: Oops yes, I've fixed that,its only epsilon dependent.